# Navicat Premium reports syntax error while MySQL works?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, navicat

Hi when i was using Navicat premium for my database it reported syntax error for this sql file :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `mounts_id`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mounts_id`;
CREATE TABLE `mounts_id` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Sans nom',
  `scrollID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stats` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of mounts_id
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('2', 'Amande Sauvage', '7807', '125=1');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('3', 'Ebene', '7808', '125=2|119=1.25');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('4', 'Rousse Sauvage', '7809', '125=1');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('9', 'Ebene Ivoire', '7810', '125=1|119=2.50|138=2.5');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('10', 'Rousse', '7811', '125=1');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('11', 'Ivoire Rousse', '7812', '125=0.5|138=2.5');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('12', 'Ebene Rousse', '7813', '125=0.6|119=1.65');
```

while it works perfectly in MySQL workbench. Heres the error from navicat:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table struct' at line 1
[Err] 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `mounts_id`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mounts_id`;
CREATE TABLE `mounts_id` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Sans nom',
  `scrollID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stats` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of mounts_id
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('2', 'Amande Sauvage', '7807', '125=1');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('3', 'Ebene', '7808', '125=2|119=1.25');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('4', 'Rousse Sauvage', '7809', '125=1');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('9', 'Ebene Ivoire', '7810', '125=1|119=2.50|138=2.5');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('10', 'Rousse', '7811', '125=1');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('11', 'Ivoire Rousse', '7812', '125=0.5|138=2.5');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('12', 'Ebene Rousse', '7813', '125=0.6|119=1.65');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('15', 'Turquoise', '7814', '125=2|176=1.25');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('16', 'Ivoire', '7815', '125=2|138=2');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('17', 'Indigo', '7816', '123=1.25|125=2');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('18', 'Dorée', '7817', '125=2|124=2.50');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('19', 'Poupre', '7818', '119=1.25|125=2');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('20', 'Amande', '7819', '174=0.1');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('21', 'Emeraude', '7820', '125=0.5|128=100');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('22', 'Orchidée', '7821', '126=1.25|125=2');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('23', 'Prune', '7822', '125=0.5|117=50');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('33', 'Amande Dorée', '7823', '174=0.2|124=4|125=2|182=100');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('34', 'Amande Ebene', '7824', '125=1');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('35', 'Amande Emeraude', '7825', '125=1|128=100|182=100|174=0.2');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('36', 'Amande Indigo', '7826', '174=0.2|125=2|123=1.65|182=100');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('37', 'Amande Ivoire', '7827', '174=0.2|125=2|119=1.65|182=100');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('38', 'Amande Rousse', '7828', '174=0.2|125=1|182=50');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('39', 'Amande Turquoise', '7829', '174=0.2|125=2|176=2.50|182=100');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('40', 'Amande Orchidée', '7830', '174=0.2|125=2|126=1.65|182=100');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('41', 'Amande Pourpre', '7831', '174=0.2|125=2|118=1.65|182=100');
INSERT INTO `mounts_id` VALUES ('42', 'Dorée Ebène', '7832', '125=1|123=4|119=1.65');
```

so mind someone explain why?

Comment: well i just did compared how the made table looks in MySQL workbench and navicat and its interesting that in workbench its completly as it should be but in navicat the stats are dispalced with (BLOB) what does that mean ? o.o